# Rails and created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, date

I do:

```
Order.find(:all, :conditions => "created_at>='#{DateTime.now.year}-#{month}-1' and created_at<='#{Date.new(DateTime.now.year, month.to_i, -1)}'")
```

That is working fine except that everything created on the last day of the month is not included. Created_at might contain: "2010-09-30 18:34:09". That is NOT less than or equal to "2010-09-30". I know that I could just change the method to this:

```
Order.find(:all, :conditions => "created_at>='#{DateTime.now.year}-#{month}-1' and created_at<='#{Date.new(DateTime.now.year, month.to_i, -1)} 23:59:59'")
```

...but that seems kind of wrong. Is there a smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the right way to do it, IMHO.  The representation of a time as `2010-09-30 18:34:09` is conceptually just a human-friendly display of a single number.  So  think of it as doing comparisons against a number.  Therefore it makes sense to be explicit about the minimum and maximum values of the number in question.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use

```
< Date.today.next_month.beginning_of_month
```

to get everything less than the next month.

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve your issue but you should make use of Rails' Ruby extensions here. You can do things like `1.month.ago` which will return a DateTime object representing the current date minus 1 month.

Other methods you might expect are defined as well. `4.days.from_now`, `3.days.since(Date.yesterday)`, etc.

Comment: I know these but how would you use them in the above example?